# How to make package an angular project

Tags: angular, npm, build, command-line-interface, publish

i have an angular project. My question is that can i make an packege my project , then i can use this packege other angular project. For example
lets assume that i made an base-layout angular project. And they have html.ts component.ts etc...
I want to be able to use all of these as a package in other projects.

i did try npm build command and then appear dist folder in my project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Znxu.png) and then i published but i can't use this project

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/libraries